# Should the voice button become a permanent addition for search fields?

Tags: search, design, ux-field, responsive

**E.g. This search box on Guardian.com's website shows the voice button.**

[image]

While this is a desktop example, on Mobile the voice button is way below (out of focus) near the space bar of the keyboard. Since the voice button invokes search, should the User be present this option within the search bar?

**E.g. Google iOS App (current)**

[image]

**E.g. Google iOS App (with voice button)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the surge in mobile/tablet access and the rapid advancements and usage of voice services I would say yes of course.  It conveys a smoother user experience and you are always better designing with a forward thinking mind frame